# Why is the html tags text in red?

Tags: html, tags, center

[red tags image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4rcc.png)

As you can see, the "center" tags are in red, is this a bad thing? should I change something?

Comment: The `<center>` element was deprecated ages ago and is considered obsolete. Use CSS to center instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

`<center>` element is depecated. Use this instead:

```
<h1 style="text-align:center">Clairo</h1>
```

Comment: Worse. The `<center>` tag is [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features)!